# When I create an Article, preUpdate and postUpdate events aren't triggered. Did anyone know to solve that issue?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

I followed the instructions on https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-listeners and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. But the events doesn't triggered.

Event Listener take the slug and if the slug is the same, than I put the Id from the article to the slug.

```
namespace App\EventListener;


use App\Entity\Article;
use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use App\Service\SlugifyService;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;


class SlugIndexer implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $repository;
    private $slugify;

public function __construct(ArticleRepository $repository, SlugifyService $slugifyService)
{
    $this->repository = $repository;
    $this->slugify = $slugifyService;
}
public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        Events::postPersist,
        Events::preUpdate,
    ];
}

public function preUpdate(Article $article, PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
{
    $articleSlug = $this->slugify->slugify($article->getTitle());
    if ($this->repository->findOneBy(['slug' => $articleSlug])) {
        $articleSlug .= '-' . $article->getId();
    }

    $article->setSlug($articleSlug);
}

public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $article = $args->getObject();

    if (!($article instanceof Article)) {
        return;
    }

    $articleSlug = $this->slugify->slugify($article->getTitle());
    if ($this->repository->findOneBy(['slug' => $articleSlug])) {
        $articleSlug .= '-' . $article->getId();
    }
    $article->setSlug($articleSlug);
    $args->getObjectManager()->persist($article);
    $args->getObjectManager()->flush();

}
```

}

This is code from my Article entity.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\User\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 */
class Article implements EntityInterface
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lead;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $publishedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     *
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User\User", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $author;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLead(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lead;
    }

    public function setLead(string $lead): self
    {
        $this->lead = $lead;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublishedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->publishedAt;
    }

    public function setPublishedAt(\DateTimeInterface $publishedAt): self
    {
        $this->publishedAt = $publishedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAuthor(): ?User
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function setAuthor(?User $author): self
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

ArticleController
This is the code how I creating a new article.

```
/**
     * @Route(path="/article", methods={"POST", "GET"})
     */
    public function create(Request $request, SlugifyService $slugifyService): Response
    {
        $article = new Article();
        $form = $this->createForm(ArticleFormType::class, $article);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $article->setPublishedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
            $this->repository->save($article);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_category_view', [
                'slug' => $article->getCategory()->getSlug()
            ]);
        }
        return $this->render('layouts/article/createArticle.html.twig', [
            'articleForm' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: services.yaml file look like this           App\EventListener\SlugIndexer:
        tags:
            - { name: 'doctrine.event_listener', event: 'preUpdate' }
            - { name: 'doctrine.event_listener', event: 'postPersist' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the EvenetListener and now all works

```
<?php


namespace App\EventListener;


use App\Entity\Article;
use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use App\Service\SlugifyService;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;


class SlugIndexer implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $repository;
    private $slugify;

    public function __construct(ArticleRepository $repository, SlugifyService $slugifyService)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->slugify = $slugifyService;
    }
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::preUpdate,
            Events::postPersist,
        ];
    }

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $article = $args->getObject();
        $articleSlug = $this->slugify->slugify($article->getTitle());
        if ($this->repository->findOneBy(['slug' => $articleSlug])) {
            $articleSlug .= '-' . $article->getId();
        }
        $article->setSlug($articleSlug);
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $article = $args->getObject();

        if (!($article instanceof Article)) {
            return;
        }

        $articleSlug = $this->slugify->slugify($article->getTitle());
        if ($this->repository->findOneBy(['slug' => $articleSlug])) {
            $articleSlug .= '-' . $article->getId();
        }
        $article->setSlug($articleSlug);
        $args->getObjectManager()->persist($article);
        $args->getObjectManager()->flush();

    }
```

And on Entity I put

```
   /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
```